# When to experience NieR: Automata for the first time after playing NieR: Replicant?

Tags: nier-automata, nier, nier-replicant-1.22474487139

*Please keep this as spoiler-free as possible, I (and others stumbling over this question since I haven't found answers for it either) might not be in the x-th playthrough yet – still a bit to go, so asking in advance.*

Since the remaster of **NieR: Replicant/Gestalt** received a new ending to tie more connections to **NieR: Automata** I'm wondering when I should leave the "first" game be for now and experience the second game for the first time.

**Does the new ending spoil anything I shouldn't know starting into Automata or is it really just to bridge some questions or create new references/callbacks in the second game?**

*I know possible answers might be subjective, so please try to consider an as objective standpoint as possible. I don't mind vague answers, if they avoid spoilers.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: don't worry about it.

Both games ultimately were made to be entirely separate experiences. Both spoiler each other to some small extents, but I don't think that any order is particularly 'better' than any other possible order.

That said though, Nier Replicant's new ending will not really 'spoil' anything more for Automata than the rest of the base game really did. The ending DOES have things that call back to certain themes or points from Automata, and as it was made after Automata exists, it clearly influenced the ending in ways that wouldn't have happened if it was included with the original game from the start.

Gun to my head, 'pick an order or perish' scenario, I guess I would recommend:

Replicant's Original Endings -> Automata -> Replicant's Last Ending

But any different slotting of Automata would have it's own different benefits.

Comment: Well, that's more or less what I expected. Indeed going to switch games after ending D then, I guess.

Comment: Basically (correct me if I assume wrongly) the links between the games are mostly just a 'I understood this reference' if you played both instead of actually being huge things/spoilers from the other game

Comment: @Fredy31 It's mostly just an added story behind ending 5, twisting a few more plot points a tiny bit with no direct impact on Automata. It adds more context to some aspects of Automata without direct spoilers.